# Run a program with a specific set of DLLs?

Tags: c#, windows, dll

Is it possible to run a program against a specific binary in a specific directory, rather than the one that is currently installed on the system?  I also cannot modify the source of the application.

Comment: What do you mean by "currently installed on the system" and "against"?

Comment: very not flexible. may I ask why?

Comment: @elyashiv There is a bug in the the library that is currently being fixed but I want to have a solution until then.

Comment: Please clarify if "binary" means .Net assembly or native DLL.

Comment: It is possible to redirect DLL loading through a manifest and/or app.config, but I'm not very experienced with that so I'll leave it to others to expand it to a full answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry, I mean native DLLs.

Comment: Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/01/24/517221.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a native DLL then you just need to place the DLL in the same folder as the executable. The [DLL search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) looks in that folder first.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get is to place an updated DLL in the same directory as the .exe.

Here is the precedence list for how a program finds DLLs to load (excluding well-known DLLs).

1. The directory where the executable module for the current process is located.
2. The current directory.
3. The Windows system directory. The GetSystemDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
4. The Windows directory. The GetWindowsDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
5. The directories listed in the PATH environment variable.

If you need to specify an arbitrary directory, then item #2 is your friend. You can cd / into the target directory and then run your .exe from that location using the full path. Or, you can create a windows shortcut and specify "Start in:" value to set the current directory for the application. This will not work as desired if the .exe in question changes its working directory.

Update: While it is now apparent to me that this advice is out of date, it is also the only advice that touches on using "a specific binary in a specific directory," which i read to mean arbitrary directories that may not be the directory an .exe is installed it. 
Also, now i see that this was tagged with "C#", which does make my answer exceptionally lame due to the availability of .manifest, i think?

Comment: This is utterly misleading. The current directory hasn't been that high on the search list for years now. Having it that high is a large security hole and MS dealt with that by the safe DLL search mode. The details are in the topic linked from my answer. It is boggling that anyone would suggest using working dir to search for DLLs. It's an apalling idea.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to load the DLLs dynamically with LoadLibrary call. That way you can specify the full path to the DLL copy you like to use.

Comment: +1 if DLL in question is native DLL. First one loaded will be used by other LoadLibrary calls... other side of DLL hell :)